# Django "can't set attribute" in model

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this one:

```
class MyReport(models.Model):
    group_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    test        = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, default=get_current_user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_objects = UserFilterManager()

    @property
    def location(self):
        return self.test.location
```

to which I added a *location* property.
I get this error at run-time. I pasted only parts below my latest call, which was to len() in this case (I know, use *count* instead).

```
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 240, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 75, in __iter__
    setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I cannot figure why the error? If I call it *locationx* then there is no error.

Are there some special property definition rules for Django?

How could I debug this?

I added the property since I added the *test* indirection and want to change as little code as possible. I could, of course, just change each `report.location` to `report.test.location`, but that's a nuisance. It would be great if I could define an alias for DB searches so I would need to change those either.

**EDIT**: To answer the comments:

1. I do not want to set the value, I just want a property (getter). I want to be able to do `report.location` instead adding an indirection `report.test.location` (don't want to change existing code where location was inside the report model).
2. `self.test.location` and `report.test.location` work, and also `reports.locationx` works as well.
3. I mentioned this above, but I will repeat. All I did was to call len() on a query, e.g. `len(MyReport.objects.all())`.

Here is a full trace from the Eclipse console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-win32-x86_64\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 765, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-win32-x86_64\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 378, in evaluateExpression
    sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % (result,))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 234, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 75, in __iter__
    setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: If you want to set the value of `self.test.location` as well then define a [setter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) for `location`: `@location.setter`.

Comment: Tip: put `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace`just before property's return an try to access `self.test.location`. ;-)

Comment: You haven't shown what you are doing to trigger this error.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem was a name clash.

Apparently when querying the DB I had:

`objs = MyReport.objects.annotate(location=F('test__location'))`

This added `location` to the objects (didn't see it in `__dict__`, but maybe I just missed it). This means I could give up the property since I could call `report_instance.location`. Of course, this means that all places that access MyReport I need to add the annotation (a special manager?).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. I had the same problem, then discovered a property was stored on the model with the same name I was trying to annotate to.

Comment: properties will not show in `instance.__dict__`.    They will appear in `instance.__class__.__dict__`  What you are actually not understanding here is the object model for Python classes.  I would suggest looking more into how *descriptors* work in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Just had a similar problem that seemed to be resolved by making sure I didn't annotate with an alias that was the same name as the property I was trying to call.

Comment: Same here! It happened to me even with fields with the `@property` decorator. Names cannot overlap. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add a setter method and the MyReport.location will be able to be set.

```
class MyReport(models.Model):
    group_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    test        = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, default=get_current_user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_objects = UserFilterManager()


    _location = None

    @property
    def location(self):
        if self._location is not None:
            return self._location
        return self.test.location

    @location.setter
    def location(self, value):
        self._location = value
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to ensure that `test` is set:

```
 @property
 def location(self):
     return self.test.location if self.test else None
```

Comment: The `location` function is **not called** at all. It does not matter what the function does (I tried printing a string and returning `None`). For some reason it does not like the name I need to use - *sheet* in this particular case.